# how to use regular pdo in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

i am used to writing regular pdo statements into php how can i continue doing that without having to learn active records or use whatever else method there is in CI

i did something like this

```
$sql = "select column1,column2 from table where column_id = :column_id and column_2 = :something"
$query = $db->query($sql);
$query->bindParam(":column_id", $_GET['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(":something", $_GET['something'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
{
   print $row->data;
}
```

rather than using $_GET i can probably use $this->uri->segment() 
which hopefully works with this...

I looked at active record and that looks like a huge bad idea, i dont know what Ellislab was thinking. no clue how complex queries can go into them. I am a newb learning from nettuts i can be wrong and please show me if i am. just speaking from what i have learned so far.

writing query statments the otherway such as

$query = $this->db->query("my sql statement") i would have to escape each value i am querying with codeigniters escape methods or just use mysql_real_escape_string. which is something i could of done to begin with before diving into the mvc world but i chose pdo because its something that already works well.

how can i implement what i am already used to?? I dont mind modifying core files , ill hopefully end up learning all the classes to reverse engineer it but until that day comes i'll have hopefully written my own mvc.

thanks

Comment: If you're not willing to learn the method CI uses, you might be better off without it. MVC frameworks and their database handling are often so closely coupled that trying to apply your own just asks for trouble all the way down the road.

Comment: can you please explain how it can be trouble? cant i just add my query into a method and add it in a controller somewhere ??

Comment: Later when you run into bugs or problems you can never be sure whether it's because of your custom DB handler or something else. It's very hard to give advice later on when you're not using the standard setup. Also, as mentioned in the answer's comments, the framework does a lot of work for you so in the long run you'll save time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I fail to see how this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('column1,column2')
                 ->from('table')
                 ->where('column_id',$this->input->get('value'))
                 ->where('column_2',$this->input->get('something'))
                 ->get();
return $query->results();
```

"looks like alot of extra work" rather than this:

```
$sql = "select column1,column2 from table where column_id = :column_id and column_2 = :something"
$query = $db->query($sql);
$query->bindParam(":column_id", $_GET['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(":something", $_GET['something'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Keep in mind that AR **automatically escapes**, so you don't worry about SQL injections.

If you're more used to query bindings, you can also do

```
$sql = "select column1,column2 from table where column_id = ? and column_2 = ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->uri->segment(3), $something);
```

and take advantage of parametrization, without using Active Record class.

Nothing prevents you from using PDO, or even mysql_* for what that matters, instead of Active Record class. And your query has nothing that prevents CI from using it - apart from the `$_GET` array which you must enable, but can easily subsitute with `$this->input->get()` or fetch manually the URI segment or have it passed automatically to the controller's method, as usually happens.

You say "am a newb learning from nettuts" , but still say that Ellislabs doesn't know what it's doing; altough lightweight and far from perfect CI has a solid community, is actively developed and its general consensus is quite high; and if it decides to have the Active Record the way it is, there's a reason.

Also, consider that other more proper and real ORMs, like [**Propel**](http://www.propelorm.org/) or Doctrine, use a similar style in running queries (and you can use them too, instead of AR if you like it), taking advantage of PHP5 concatenation. An example taken right from the frontpage of propel:

```
$books = BookQuery::create()  // retrieve all books...
  ->filterByPublishYear(2009) // ... published in 2009
  ->orderByTitle()            // ... ordered by title
  ->joinWith('Book.Author')   // ... with their author
  ->find();
```

So I see nothing strange in the way CI's Active Record is implemented or structured. If your code is not running, please give more details, like error codes and so on, so we can actually understand *why* it's not working.

**IMPORTANT:**

I just read the [**changelog**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html) from the latest version; try downloading it (version 2.10), as they state:

> Added a PDO driver to the Database driver.

Answer (score 0):

You're not gaining anything by using CI's DB class if you're not using ActiveRecord or the other functions.  Why not just use PDO natively?

By the way, you could do the exact same thing this way:

```
$result = $this->db->
    select(array('column1', 'column2'))->
    where(array(
        'column1' => $this->input->get('value'),
        'column2' => $this->input->get('something')
    ))->get('table')->result();

print_r($result);
```

Comment: active records looks like alot of extra work when time comes when i have to write 10 or more lines of a query. i have tried using pdo natively into it and it didnt work. i am used to using the :type not the others. the  example you provided i would still have to escape, trim, and whatever else necessary to the gets and posts.

Comment: ActiveRecord will put ticks around all fields, the input class will XSS filter, and all you'd have to do is trim().  Sounds like a lot less work to me ;).  New is scary, but worth the effort here.

Comment: new is scary just extra stuff to learn, hopefully in time ill get used to it and thanks for your input. btw, my friend just created an mvc similar to CI and he uses pdo the same way i described in my question. do you think in the long run it can cause problems?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  They're all just tools to make your life easier.  Whichever one makes you most productive--go with that.  I've actually found ActiveRecord to be one of the best things about CI.  You'd be amazed at the increased productivity.  And you can always fallback to writing out the complex queries by hand.  That said, find a way to load PDO as a CI library wrapper or something that's accessible everywhere in CI, and get on with your life ;)